# Can the setKeepAliveInBackground method be set to display as optional?

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

This API ensures the Android app runs in the background as per the worklight documentation. But with this, user is always shown a notification that the app is running in the background in the notification bar and user can not clear it.

Is there anyway to make this notification display as optional and not to show it in case not required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in the documentation for Worklight 6.2 in regards to this API call:

> For Android devices and hybrid applications, to ensure that the
>   application will continue to run in the background use
>   WL.App.setKeepAliveInBackground(true, options). Using this API binds
>   the application to a foreground service. By default, if no options are
>   specified, the application's name and icon are displayed. Tapping on
>   the notification takes the user back to the last activity that made
>   the call to WL.App.setKeepAliveInBackground(true). **The notification is**
>   **present until the app exits, or WL.App.setKeepAliveInBackground(false)**
>   **is called**. For details on using the options to change the text, the
>   icon, or which activity gets called when the user presses on the
>   notification, see the method setKeepAliveInBackground as defined in
>   the WL.App class.

Here is a link to the Knowledge Center outlining this:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/t_keeping_app_running_in_background.html?lang=en

Here is a link to the WL.App class the above is referencing:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjavascript-client/html/WL.App.html?cp=SSZH4A_6.2.0%2F10-0-0-1-2

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I may not have been clear in what I would like to have happen. I would like to keep the application alive, running in the background, however I do not want a notification that the application is running in the background.